# TYPO3: Get the values in fluid from inline elements

Tags: variables, typo3, fluid

I managed to create an own inline content element (on tt_content table) but when i try to get the values on the frontend via fluid, i get nothing.

I debugged the {data} variable and on the column that my data are saved, there is an integer. I suppose it reads the number of the content elements which were created on the foreign table (accordion). How can i get those values?

At this point the {data} variables reads the tt_content table and the column that has the integer reads the number of content elements on the table accordion.

**I suppose no code is necessary. If it is necessary, feel free to comment the part of the code you would like to review.**

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a DataProcessor to your TypoScript creating the content element, which fetch your accordion records. Example:

```
tt_content {
    yourContentElementName < lib.contentElement
    yourContentElementName.templateName = YourContentElementName
    yourContentElementName.dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
        10 {
            if.isTrue.field = fieldInTtContentWithInteger

            table = your_accordion_table

            pidInList = this
            where.field = uid
            where.intval = 1
            where.dataWrap = field_pointing_to_ttcontent_record = |

            as = accordions
        }
    }
}
```